# Creating chart in microsoft word from existing table in it

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a CRM template word file

I have a table in it, which will be dynamically generated

How can I draw a chart for particular table column? say Goal status column?[image]

Whenever I goto insert and add a chart, it adds a excel sheet and when I try to select the chart and change data, it is not allowing me to pick the table that is already there

I am able to click on "Select column" and then Insert -> Object -> Microsoft chart object and it generates the graph for the static content. But when I do the same for the column with repeating xml mapped value, its not working

Comment: [Converting Tables to Charts](http://wordribbon.tips.net/T007791_Converting_Tables_to_Charts.html)

Comment: Yes, this works for normal table, but I am trying for a table which will be dynamically generated by CRM